# Java > Drawing multiple rectangles on an existing image

Tags: java, awt

I am comparing two images based on their pixels and need to draw a rectangle around the mismatched pixel value. It correctly draws thew rectangle around the first pixel mismatched but there on wards it doesn't.

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {  
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {  
        result[row][col] = img1.getRGB(col, row);  
        result1[row][col] = img2.getRGB(col, row);  
        if(result[row][col] != result1[row][col]){  
         try {  
            g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);  
            g.setColor(Color.red);  
            g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0F));  
            g.drawRect(col-5, row-12, 35, 35);  
            } finally {  
            g.dispose();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Draw the image `g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);` once, before you start looping - otherwise you're painting the image over all the work you have already done

Comment: And don't dispose of a `Graphics` context until you're finished with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);` will draw over anything that was previously painted, not a good idea inside your loop
- `g.dispose` could prevent anything from been updated/painted to the context in the future. You should really only call it when you are completely done

As a quick test, I took the following images as input...

[image: img1] [image: img2]

Ran it through...

```
BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
BufferedImage img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));

int width = img1.getWidth();
int height = img1.getHeight();

BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = temp.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, null);

for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        int result = img1.getRGB(col, row);
        int result1 = img2.getRGB(col, row);
        if (result != result1) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0F));
                g.drawRect(col - 5, row - 12, 35, 35);
        }
    }
}
g.dispose();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(temp));
```

Which output...

[image: Result]